# why pubspec environment / sdk / uses " '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0' " instead of " ^2.7.0 "

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, semantic-versioning

to my, admittedly very limited, understanding of [semver](https://semver.org/)

this

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ^2.7.0
```

is equivalent to this

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.7.0 <3.0.0'
```

this format is strictly enforced for package publishing

```sh
Package validation found the following error:
* ^ version constraints aren't allowed for SDK constraints since older versions of pub don't support them.
  Expand it manually instead:
  
  environment:
    sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
Sorry, your package is missing a requirement and can't be published yet.
```

is there any reason why flutter uses the `latter` in place of the `former` approach,

which is arguably more familiar and [consistent](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#using-packages) ?

Comment: SemVer doesn't actually define range specifiers (yet), and even when they get around to it, there's so much variation between the top five or so tools, that it's not going to be much use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some definitions :

- `^2.7.0` is `Caret syntax`
- `>=2.7.0 <3.0.0` is `Traditional syntax`

And based on the [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax):

> Because caret syntax was introduced in Dart 1.8.3, it requires an SDK constraint (using traditional syntax) to ensure that older versions of pub don’t try to process it. For example:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.8.3 <3.0.0'
```